# Lookin for the the correct way to alter a field

Tags: forms

I am trying to find the correct way to alter a field on a multilingual Drupal 7 site. I am using multilingual nodes but not multilingual fields.

I can alter the field with:

```
$form['field_uploaded_files']['#prefix'] = 'This is a test';
```

This works without a hitch.

If I try and then do something slightly more complicated like

```
$form['field_uploaded_files'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#upload_validators']['_app_magic_number_validator'] = array($form_id);
```

then it does not work at all.  I have tried with and without [LANGUAGE_NONE]. I have tried with and without [0].

I am at a loss for why this is not working and would appreciate any help.

Comment: What's not working? Your validator isn't called? Maybe it's supposed to be `$form['field_uploaded_files'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#upload_validators'][] = '_app_magic_number_validator';` or  `$form['field_uploaded_files'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#upload_validators']['_app_magic_number_validator'] = $form_id;`

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. Unfortunately, neither of them appear to call. _app_magic_number_validator. I Have a watchdog function that should log if they are called. Any other ideas are greatly appreciated.